# UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-forms-4

I'm trying to run this code:

```
GetRepsButton.Command = new Command(async () =>
            {
                var url = @"https://url";

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //crashes here
                var test = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            });
```

And when I do, the entire app crashes and the output window shows this error:

```
ROR: +[MSWrapperLogger MSWrapperLog:tag:level:]/7 Unhandled Exception:
UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00020] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:89 
  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr action) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.g.cs:342 
  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.OnDispose () [0x00016] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:41 
  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.g.cs:959 
  at
 Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:143 
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'SelectRep.xaml.cs:110,1' to void NameSpace.<ClientPicker_SelectedIndexChanged1>d__3.MoveNext () [0x0000c].
```

Although I dont think I should have to since i'm not doing anything with the UI, I have tried `InvokeOnMainThread` which does not work. I've also tried changing to .Result instead of await, and I've tried `GetAsync` and reading the content, along with using `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`. All cause this same error.

Any ideas? I'm using Xamarin forms 4 pre 7.

Comment: can you provide more context around that line of code?  The stacktrace looks like it is coming from a gesture recognizer, is that correct?

Comment: @Jason I haven't made any gesture recognizers in the project at all. I think that is internal code to xamarin.ios. 

If I comment out this one .getstringaync line, the app runs fine.

Comment: I would "assume" this awaited call is within a `void` return method somewhere and thus causes the chained failure within some UI code (yours or the Forms4 preview code, would not be able to tell without more context of how/where you are using/calling that httpclient async method.

Comment: @SushiHangover the code was inside a `Clicked` Event(`private async void ClientPicker_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)`) on a `Button`, which the only choice is `void` as far as I understand? However I changed it to set the Command with an async command and still have the same problem. I updated my question to show the full code block. Am I misunderstanding how to go about async calls on button clicks?

Comment: @SushiHangover this also happens if I use `WebClient.DownloadString()` which isn't async at all.

Comment: @Kyle No, you have it right (void-based event handlers are unavoidable...). Are you removing that event handler anywhere? Something is causing the "strange" crash. Wondering when you say `ClientPicker_SelectedIndexChanged1` is on a button, is it a button, a picker? ??

Comment: I'm not removing the event anywhere, and it's on a Button. Sorry I know it has Picker in the name which is confusing. The code was originally running whenever a picker changed and using the picker values, but I've been trying to narrow down the code so I put it on a button and hard coded values to get the code as minimal as possible.

Comment: After 8 hours of trying to get this to work, I switched to Visual Studio 2017 instead of the 2019 preview and it works fine. I assume this is a bug with the version of xamrarin.ios or mono that ships with the 2019 preview I guess....

Answer (score 5):

Use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
  //your code
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Good!! work for me. i use it with "Browser.OpenAsync(" command