# iOS HttpClient crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

This is my code

```
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
         MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         var jsonstring = await client.GetStringAsync("https://asdasdadasd" + 
              url);
```

Occur this error:

> 2019-03-29 11:18:43.901 Eliant.App.iOS[3859:3548233]
>   [AppCenterCrashes]  ERROR: +[MSWrapperLogger
>   MSWrapperLog:tag:level:]/7 Unhandled Exception:
>   UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are 
>   calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread. at
>   UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00020] in
>
> Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIK
>
> it/UIApplication.cs:89  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr action) [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.g.cs:342
>   at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.OnDispose () [0x00016] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:41
>   at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.g.cs:959
>   at Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.6.0.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:143

Any ideas?

Commenting out await client.GetStringAsync() makes the app work fine. I've tried running it using Device invoke on the main thread (even though I don't think there is any reason I should need to do that?) I've tried .result instead of await, and I've tried getasync().content.readstringasync and always have the same issue.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that include where the above code is being called from. You have not provided enough details for us to be able to identify the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Just those three lines of code, with nothing else, was being run on a clicked event of a button. The same error also happens on if placed in selectedindexchanged of a picker.

It was running on the main thread, and I even tried invokeonmainthread.

I ended up 'fixing' it by downgrading to Visual Studio 2017. If I go back to Visual Studio 2019, the same thing happens, so I assume this is some sort of bug in Xamarin.IOS version that ships with 2019.

Comment: Same as error as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423904/uikit-uikitthreadaccessexception-uikit-consistency-error-you-are-calling-a-uik#comment97572082_55423904 File an issue on Xamarin.iOS github's repo

Comment: yes,issue is same but how to solve this

Comment: which HTTP client implementation are you using? CHeck it in ios project settings in iOS build section

Comment: This also happens if i swap out HttpClient for WebClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to make this call on the UI thread (from the error contents).

Have you tried ensuring that this code is running on the UI thread? See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread) for details on how you should be able to do this.

Essentially you should be doing something like:

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // code which needs to be run on UI thread
});
```